# How to apply multiple row names at once

Tags: r, dataframe, row

Lets say I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
> df
 Age       Sex       Height        Width        Weight 
 ..         ..        ..            ..            ..
 ..         ..        ..            ..            ..
 ..         ..        ..            ..            ..
```

I also have a 5x5 matrix:

```
> M
PC1       PC2       PC3        PC4        PC5       
1.9747188 1.0135635 0.935994  0.73762825 0.60932788 
0.5570735 0.1467587 0.885155  0.07772792 0.05304007 
0.8289874 0.9067153 0.959755  0.90671530 0.95975536 
0.3563735 0.7038322 0.828987  0.90671530 0.95975536
0.9359947 0.7376282 0.60932   0.90671530 0.95975536
```

I am trying to take the column names from one dataframe and make them the row names of another. So that i would have something like this

```
         PC1       PC2       PC3        PC4        PC5       
Age    1.9747188 1.0135635 0.935994  0.73762825 0.60932788 
Sex    0.5570735 0.1467587 0.885155  0.07772792 0.05304007 
Heigh  0.8289874 0.9067153 0.959755  0.90671530 0.95975536 
Width  0.3563735 0.7038322 0.828987  0.90671530 0.95975536
Weight 0.9359947 0.7376282 0.60932   0.90671530 0.95975536
```

But I can't just rename each row manually, because I am putting it into a function, so i need a method that generalizes this.

Any suggestions eppreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a function

```
f1 <- function(dat1, dat2) {
         stopifnot(ncol(dat1) == nrow(dat2))
         row.names(dat2) <- colnames(dat1)
         dat2
 }

f1(df, M)
```

Comment: Yes this was perfect. In fact, all I needed was: row.names(dat2) <- colnames(dat1)
Thank you!